# Javascript toggle button not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, toggle

I'm developing a mobile site with the jquery mobile framework and have encountered a problem with showing/hiding a div when a javascript onclick event is activated. It works fine in my desktop safari browser (and other desktop broswers), yet not on iPhone's version of safari.

The page in question is:

http://m.bestoddsindia.com/odds/#/odds/cricket/competitions-level1/competitions-level2/competitions-level3/bookmakers-outright-odds.php?comp1=New%20Zealand%20V%20South%20Africa%20Tests&markettype=2&bettype=Series%20Correct%20Score

When working properly, clicking on any of the list links will display more content directly below. I was wondering if there was some kind of conflict between the javascript and the jquery mobile library when in the iPhone environment.

You can view the basic code structure here: http://jsfiddle.net/bestoddsglobal/vxdCL/21/

(Note it doesn't work in the jsfiddle environment either!)

Comment: Its working fine.Please check http://jsfiddle.net/vxdCL/22/

Comment: In chrome it doesn't appear to register the onclick handler in jsFiddle, I had to change it to register the event on page load in the script part to get it to work.  Safari may well suffer from this problem as well.

Comment: The jsFiddle just needs to be set to have the code in the head section (drop down at the upper left) so that your function is properly defined in the global scope.  That makes the jsFiddle work.

Comment: Ahh yes I see, that's the difference with the one @Matrix linked to.  Sorry, I've never used jsfiddle myself before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have jQuery referenced, you can change the toggle function to this:

```
function toggle_display(strID)
{
    $('#' + strID).toggle();
    return false;
}
```

The documentation for this function is [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)